# Java Regular Expression string match

Tags: java, regex

I need a help. I am writing a method which will return true if `1954` is in string `images/deal/129277/1954-bonus.jpg`. I can use string.contains but it won't be accurate always. Instead I want it to return true if 1954 is at exact place. Below sourceKey is `images/deal/129277/1954-bonus.jpg` and oldImageId is `1954`.

Below code is not working.

```
private boolean keyMatches(String sourceKey, String oldImageId){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)-(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceKey);
    return oldImageId.equals(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Comment: you need to use find function.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
String s = "images/deal/129277/1954-bonus.jpg";
String oldImageId = "1954";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)-(.*)").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(oldImageId.matches(m.group(3)));
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: or better `if (m.matches())`

Comment: why do you call `find()` into while loop? It is enought to call it once.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "images/deal/129277/1954-bonus.jpg";
    String s1 = "images/deal/1954/1911254-bonus.jpg";
    System.out.println(s.matches(".*/1954\\-.*"));
    System.out.println(s1.matches(".*/1954\\-.*"));
}
```

O/P:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one mistake in your code. Matcher does not return any group unless you call `find()` or `match()` method before and these methods returned `true`.

So, your code should be modified as following:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceKey);
return matcher.find() ? oldImageId.equals(matcher.group(3)) : null;
```

I am leaving it to you to verify that your regex is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex lookahead and `String#matches()` your function could be a one-liner like

```
private boolean keyMatches(String sourceKey, String oldImageId){
    return sourceKey.matches(".*/(?!.*/)"+oldImageId+"-.*");
}
```

I tried the following tests with `1954` placed at various parts of the URL to try fool the regex.

```
System.out.println(keyMatches("images/deal/129277/1954-bonus.jpg", "1954"));
System.out.println(keyMatches("images/deal/1954-pics/129277-bonus.jpg", "1954"));
System.out.println(keyMatches("123-1954/1954-00/1954/129277-bonus.jpg", "1954"));
System.out.println(keyMatches("images/deal/129277/129277-1954-bonus.jpg", "1954"));
```

***Output :***

```
true
false
false
false
```